# Dell 660s power supply specs

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 660s slim tower that I'm upgrading. I was wondering if anyone knows if the power supply has enough extra juice to power a evga GeForce gtx 750 ti SC graphics card. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 660s PC has a 220w psu, the video card requires a [minimum of a 300w PSU](https://www.evga.com/products/specs/gpu.aspx?pn=2af49523-559f-4b95-af14-f0c2a5d70b26)

So No it will not power the card.

Comment: How much would an upgraded PSU cost?

Comment: Im not sure if they make one or how much, start googling.